# JSON: All values are being converted to strings

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I am using Angular($http.post) and PHP to save a json file to the server. The saved json file is having all values converted/saved to strings including numbers and booleans. This is obviously causing a problem when the json file gets read in at a later point.

PHP Code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

$fh = fopen('savedfiles/'.$_POST['fileName'], 'w') or die("can't open file");

if(fwrite($fh, json_encode($_POST['fileData']))===FALSE){
    echo "FAILED";
}
else {

    echo "SUCCESS";
}

fclose($fh);
```

Angular/$http code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var savePromise = $http.post('save.php',{fileName:file_name,fileData:data}).
then(function(response){
  deferred.resolve(response.data);
},function(response){ 
  deferred.resolve("FAILED");
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

UPDATED: [Here is the output of saved JSON file](http://pastebin.com/gvRda4dA):

UPDATED: [Here is the data before being sent to the PHP file](http://pastebin.com/tdSrLMaf)

Comment: Please show the output of "json_encode($_POST['fileData'])"

Comment: How do you save something other than strings in a file ?

Comment: Also what happens when your `$_POST['fileName']` is `../../something.json`?

Comment: I think the problem is the php function `json_encode` is treating your incoming JSON as a giant string, even though it contains JSON

Comment: Updated post with saved output of JSON

Comment: What does the contents of `data` look like on the client, before sending it?

Comment: @Supr Updated OP with link to data before being sent

Comment: ok so what is the problem? is the problem with true false values? if yes try `true` instead of `"true"`

Comment: @imsiso The problem is that all numeric and boolean values are having quotes put around them, thus they are being read in as strings.

Comment: What is the raw value of $_POST['filename'] if you print it straight from PHP without json_encode? This doesn't seem to make any sense, but a first step to figure out what's going on would be to know what PHP is really receiving.

Comment: It outputs the name of the file: i.e. course.json

Comment: @imsiso It ouputs 'Array'

Comment: @imsiso See here: http://pastebin.com/j397rq9B

Comment: @imsiso I removed the header line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `JSON.stringify()` to convert your data to a format suitable for storage in a string and then you can parse it back again with `JSON.parse()`

```
var savePromise = $http.post('save.php',{fileName:file_name, fileData: JSON.stringify(data)}).
```

Comment: this is not useful here.because the json_encode return stringified string not the JSON object. and there is no need to turn them to string agian.(-:

Comment: This worked! I had to use stripslashes() as it was adding '\' to the content (see pastebin.com/5g3w71zS). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Note that you won't get a JSON object straight from `POST`; it's only a string, so it doesn't really make sense to `json_encode` it. It's already encoded, so just save it straight to the file without passing it through the encoder.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing json_encode on data thats already been POSTed. In this case you have a set of key value pairs and all of the values are in string format.

You need to encode them at the client side and then put your JSON string into a single field which you can POST. Then that JSON string has all of the data types preserved.

```
var json_str = JSON.stringify(myobject);
```

Now POST json_str as though it were an HTML form field.

Comment: Okay, that worked! I had to use stripslashes() as it was adding '\' to the content (see http://pastebin.com/5g3w71zS). Thanks!!!